# Firebase Realtime array populate div

Tags: arrays, firebase-realtime-database

Okay so I’m need guidance on where to start.

What I want to do is upon clicking a button in my web app which will be labelled `“search”` the web app will connect to my realism database and search the data base for the `“search criteria”` and the once found all matching cases it will create div blocks with the information inside it, in a list view and assign the ID of the div to the UID it gets back from the database.

```
    database:
    Users
    --> Country
    ---->State        
    ----->City
    ------>Post/ZipCode
    ------->UID
    --------> Users informantion
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

A great place to get started is the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) doocumentation or searching for Firecasts on YouTube (linked below).

As requested, here are some questions to ask yourself to get started and help scope out and define your new Firebase project.

- What language are you going to use?
- Are you planning on using any frameworks/libraries? e.g. For Javascript, these would include things like jQuery, Polymer, and React
- What information are you storing in your database? e.g. user profiles, private user data/settings, public indexes, username lists, etc.
- How is your database structured?
- What data is being searched? The entire database? Values in a certain location?
- What data needs to be displayed in your view?
- Is the data accessible for just the current user or is it a public database that anyone can use?
- What search criteria will be used? Is it just one filter at a time or many?

The answers to these questions aren't set in stone, but are to help you start thinking about the future of your project. They can be changed at any time as this isn't SQL where everything has to have its own schema.

If you intend on using "advanced searches" where you'll filter by multiple parameters at the same time, consider using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) instead.

I recommend looking at some Firecasts to help guide you through these questions. Here are some links to them:

- [Firebase YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/Firebase/playlists)
- [Video: Getting Started with the Firebase Realtime Database on the Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noB98K6A0TY)
- [Playlist: Firebase on the Web](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX)

Comment: i have edited my question to reflect my database structure, its not so much the fire base i need the assistance with its creating code either in PHP or java-script. To create a profile card for each user in the database. either by building a profile card template and code gets that and repeats it in the list view and populate.